# how to add hours in javascript returned by google routes in maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, time

I am using google maps to create a route with multiple stops(waypoints). i send google maps api multiple lat and lon, Google maps return route from point to point, route information like : from point 'A' to point 'b' duration = '2 hours 12 mins' and from point 'b' to point 'c' duration = '35 mins' and from point 'c' to point 'd' duration = '1 hour 20 mins'. how can i get the total time  required ? how can i add time like this in js?

Comment: What does your code/map look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you should be recieving according to the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361715
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13725
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Assuming this, you will be able to add up the `row.elemnts[0].duration.value` (which is the travel time in seconds)
with the duration.value you would like to add on.

Comment: thank you very much, this is what i needed but i dont know why i was down voted. my question is very clear though